# The Eulers Project Problem no 345 Cant understand a few lines of code

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have a problem understanding the below code . I have marked the part i didnt understand with //comment

The function 'search()' is recursively called. MaxRemaining[] array has 15 elements, Size is a const with value 15.

```
const unsigned int Size = 15;


unsigned short matrix[Size][Size] =
  {
    {   7,  53, 183, 439, 863, 497, 383, 563,  79, 973, 287,  63, 343, 169, 583 },
    { 627, 343, 773, 959, 943, 767, 473, 103, 699, 303, 957, 703, 583, 639, 913 },
    { 447, 283, 463,  29,  23, 487, 463, 993, 119, 883, 327, 493, 423, 159, 743 },
    { 217, 623,   3, 399, 853, 407, 103, 983,  89, 463, 290, 516, 212, 462, 350 },
    { 960, 376, 682, 962, 300, 780, 486, 502, 912, 800, 250, 346, 172, 812, 350 },
    { 870, 456, 192, 162, 593, 473, 915,  45, 989, 873, 823, 965, 425, 329, 803 },
    { 973, 965, 905, 919, 133, 673, 665, 235, 509, 613, 673, 815, 165, 992, 326 },
    { 322, 148, 972, 962, 286, 255, 941, 541, 265, 323, 925, 281, 601,  95, 973 },
    { 445, 721,  11, 525, 473,  65, 511, 164, 138, 672,  18, 428, 154, 448, 848 },
    { 414, 456, 310, 312, 798, 104, 566, 520, 302, 248, 694, 976, 430, 392, 198 },
    { 184, 829, 373, 181, 631, 101, 969, 613, 840, 740, 778, 458, 284, 760, 390 },
    { 821, 461, 843, 513,  17, 901, 711, 993, 293, 157, 274,  94, 192, 156, 574 },
    {  34, 124,   4, 878, 450, 476, 712, 914, 838, 669, 875, 299, 823, 329, 699 },
    { 815, 559, 813, 459, 522, 788, 168, 586, 966, 232, 308, 833, 251, 631, 107 },
    { 813, 883, 451, 509, 615,  77, 281, 613, 459, 205, 380, 274, 302,  35, 805 }
  };



unsigned int maxRemaining[Size];
unsigned int search(unsigned int row = 0, unsigned int columnMask = 0,unsigned int sum = 0, unsigned int atLeast = 0){
    if (row == Size)
        return sum;

    if (sum + maxRemaining[row] <= atLeast) //explain this line
        return 0;

    for (unsigned int column = 0; column < Size; column++)
    {
        auto mask = 1 << column;         //explain this line
        if ((columnMask & mask) != 0)    //explain this line
            continue;
        auto current = search(row + 1, columnMask | mask, sum + matrix[row][column], atLeast);  //explain whats with the 2nd parameter.
        if (atLeast < current)
            atLeast = current;
    }

    return atLeast;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: And whats with al the **'s?

Comment: If you don't understand how some code works, the best way to figure it out is to use your debugger to simply execute it, one line at a time, and observe its logic, step by step. Have you tried to run this program in a debugger, if not, why not?

Comment: Is it the C++ or the algorithm you don't understand?  We can help you with C++ meaning and syntax here but probably not the algorithm use to solve the specific problem.

Comment: I have edited the comments and tried to reformat. please see now

Comment: Are the [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) the ones you are not familiar with, or is it the algorithm itself?

Comment: i know what the algorithm does, but i cant understand how it reaches there, what is the use of bitwise here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain the lines you highlighted. Let's start by explaining the `columnMask` argument - this argument is the bitmask of all the columns used. Obviously, this mask is initially 0. Next:

```cpp
auto mask = 1 << column;
```

In this line of code, we get the bitmask for the column. Next:

```
if ((columnMask & mask) != 0)
    continue;
```

In this row, we check whether this column has already been used, if so, then we skip this column. Example, if we have `columnMask = 20 (10100)` and `mask` for the 3rd column `1 << 2 = 4 (100)`, then the logical AND operation `columnMask & mask` will not equal 0. And if we have mask for the 2nd column `1 << 1 = 2 (10)`, then `columnMask & mask` will be 0.
Next:

```
auto current = search(row + 1, columnMask | mask, sum + matrix[row][column], atLeast);
```

In the second argument, we do a logical OR operation. This is the same as addition. That is, we establish that the column with the column number is now used. The same example, if we have `columnMask = 20 (10100)` and `mask` for the 2nd column `1 << 1 = 2 (10)`, then `columnMask | mask = 22 (10110)`.

Next:

```cpp
if (sum + maxRemaining[row] <= atLeast)
        return 0;
```

As I understand it, `maxRemaining[row]` contains the sum of the maximum elements in columns from `row` to `Size-1`, inclusive. Then this condition serves to speed up the operation of the algorithm, since if `sum + maxRemaining[row]` is less than the best solution at the moment (`atLeast`), then there is no point in continuing this recursion branch, therefore 0 is returned, which essentially discards this recursion branch.

Comment: Many Thanks,  Your explanation helped me a great deal. BTW maxRemaining is just a 1D array of size 15 containing elements from the matrix which are of highest value in any column.

Comment: It seems like I understood what `maxRemaining` is doing and updated my answer accordingly. Look please.

Answer (score 0):

It's not trivial to debug this code due to the multiple recursive calls of the function `search()`.

However, you can understand the code by looking carefully at the [problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=345) question:

We define the Matrix Sum of a matrix as the maximum sum of matrix elements with each element being the only one in his row and column. For example, the Matrix Sum of the matrix below equals 3315 ( = 863 + 383 + 343 + 959 + 767):

```
  7  53 183 439 863
497 383 563  79 973
287  63 343 169 583
627 343 773 959 943
767 473 103 699 303
```

- The problem asks to you to find the maximum sum taking only such that each element is the only selected element in its row and column. So if in the first row the function chooses an element in the first column, for the second row the function must choose an element among all the columns except the first one. You have to imagine the `column mask` as bit string made of 15 bits where the least significant bit is the first column, and the most significant bit is the last column:

```
column index: 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
column mask:  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

By doing `auto mask = 1 << column;` you want to mask the *column-th* column: for instance, if column=3, the mask is:

```
column index: 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
mask:         0  0  0  0  0  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

that in decimal is equal to 8. So mask represents the current column you want to mask.

- `if ((columnMask & mask) != 0)`. Remember the problem rule: if you select an element in a column, you can't select other elements from the same column. `columnMask` stores the columns you have already selected. `&` is the bitwise-AND operator. So if `columnMask` and `mask` have the same bit equal to 1, the loop skips this column because it has already selected an element of that column.
- `columnMask | mask`. `|` is the bitwise-OR operator and is used to update the columnMask, that is setting to 1 the same bit as in `mask`.
- `if (sum + maxRemaining[row] <= atLeast) //explain this line`

I can't explain to you the role of this line because the variable `maxRemaining` is never assigned, maybe part of the code is missing.